# getting a weird error whenever I try restarting apache

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install apache, php5, mysql, and phpmyadmin. And I'm following a tutorial but this error keeps happening

here's the error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 227 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open 
configuration file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!
```

I've tried removing all of them and reinstalling but, to no avail.

I'm pulling my hair out over this so, thanks in advance! =)

edit: during the tutorial I screwed up and deleting something, lol, so I know that's the issue I just don't know what to do about it now

Comment: folders exist? file permissions (remember that apache probably runs as a user other than you or root)?

Comment: What tutorial? How did you install phpmyadmin? What distribution are you using? Does the file, in fact, exist?

Comment: this is the tutorial: http://connectwww.com/how-to-install-and-configure-apache-php-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-linux-mint/1443/

Comment: You may want to post the current apache config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back up a second.

What does that error message say?

"apache2: Syntax error on line 227 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open 
configuration file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!"

I would immediately focus on the following:

1) /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: No such file or directory
2) The Apache error log may have more information.

Let's address #1 first, well, you will do the work. I will just give some hints.

Apache can load configuration files from external sources.
I would make sure that /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf is there.
Depending on the package manageer the file might be in "/etc/phpmysql/apache.conf.example"

Check that first and see if

cp /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf.example /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf;/etc/init.d/apacheX actually brings the server up.

If that does not work look run the following: find / -iname *apache.conf*

See if you can find an example file on the local system. I would not suggest going into production with an example config but if it gets you up until you are able to test your configuration properly, and you are able to do this without any security risks then I would say no harm. You muse do the due diligence on that though.

Also, do not tear your hair out. Relax, step away for a second and while you are solving the issue stay relaxed. A clear head is important for solving system admin problems like this. When you start to internalize them you start to lose focus on solving the problem and begin focusing only on what you want to happen.

If you get really irritated you can always google "phpmysql apache.conf" and pick up an example somewhere. Believing people on the internet is bad in most cases so "buyer beware" so to speak.

I hope that this helps.